# Check if relative path exists

Tags: javascript, file, path

I have a function in a file `checkExists.js`

```
export const checkIfExists = (input) => {
   return fs.existsSync(input)
}
```

And I have a test, `test.js`, that I **cannot** edit in any way

```
import {checkIfExists} from '/checkExists'

checkIfExists('../../myTestFile.js').shouldBeTrue
```

`../../myTestFile.js` is the correct relative path to `test.js` but not to `checkExists.js`

Is there a way to resolve the path in `checkExists.js` so it can support relative paths?  I cannot pass a different path, the `checkIfExists` function must be able to do all the work.

Comment: You probably want to switch over to fs.stat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `path` module to resolve the path to the file...

```
import * as path from 'path';
...

checkIfExists(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../myTestFile.js')).shouldBeTrue
```